# Changing buttons Id's Javascript not working as intended

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the text of the same div based on clicks on two buttons. Because printed text should be different each time, I came up with the idea to change button's Id's. As you can see I assign a new id after each click :
`chA.id = ("a1A");` but it does not seem to work properly. 
The turns stop counting after I click `Button A` or `Button B` and the text will not change to what I expect. 
What do I do wrong?:

```js
 
turncount = 0;
chA = document.getElementById("ButtonA");
chB = document.getElementById("ButtonB");
PrnKey = "Intro";
hideButtons.onclick = () => {
 bint.style.display = 'none';
}
showButtons.onclick = () => {
 bint.style.display = 'inline';
 
}
DivTextBox.onclick = () => {
        bint.style.display = 'inline';
};


document.getElementById("ButtonA").onclick = function () {
 document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option A<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
 turncount ++;
 bint.style.display = 'none';

 ButtonA.innerText = `Option A turn ${turncount}`;
 ButtonB.innerText = `Option B turn ${turncount}`;
 chA.id = ("a1A");
 chB.id = ("a1B");
};
 
document.getElementById("a1A").onclick = function () {
 document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option a1A<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
 turncount ++;
 bint.style.display = 'none';
 a1A.innerText = `Option A turn ${turncount}`;
 a1B.innerText = `Option B turn ${turncount}`;
 chA.id = ("a2A");
 chB.id = ("a2B");
};
 
 document.getElementById("a1B").onclick = function () {
 document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option a1B<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
 turncount ++;
 bint.style.display = 'none';
 a1A.innerText = `Option bA turn ${turncount}`;
 a1B.innerText = `Option bB turn ${turncount}`;
 chA.id = ("b2A");
 chB.id = ("b2B");
};
 

document.getElementById("ButtonB").onclick = function () {
 bint.style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option B<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
 turncount ++;
 ButtonA.innerText = `Option bA turn ${turncount}`;
 ButtonB.innerText = `Option bB turn ${turncount}`;
 chA.id = ("b1A");
 chB.id = ("b1B");
};
 

 document.getElementById("b1A").onclick = function () {
 document.getElementById("DivTextBox").innerHTML = "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Text explaining Option a1B<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
 turncount ++;
 bint.style.display = 'none';
 b1A.innerText = `Option b1A turn ${turncount}`;
 b1B.innerText = `Option b1B turn ${turncount}`;
 chA.id = ("b2A");
 chB.id = ("b2B");
};
```

```html
<div id="DivTextBox">Here is Intro <br><br><br><br><br><br><br> T <br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>

<div id="bint">
<button id="ButtonA">
Option A
</button>
<button id="ButtonB">
Option B
</button>
</div>
<button id="hideButtons">
 Hide Buttons
 </button>
 <button id="showButtons">
 Show Buttons
 </button>
```

Comment: Your variables don't look like they were ever initialized in the first place, Are you sure this is the right code snippet?

Comment: @FeyisayoSonubi, if you do not explicitly declare the variables and do not use strict mode, they are implictly declared as variables in the window scope. So `chA` will actually be `window.chA`.

Comment: Oh wow, never thought of that, thanks, Marco!

Comment: It is not considered good practice in most cases, because it usually exposes variables to the global scope. Most teams I worked with enforce the usage of `"use strict";` so code like the above would throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

When your code runs to attach the click handlers for `a1A` and `a1B`, those elements do not yet exist, so your code throws an error `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`. If you develop in a html file and view the results in a browser like Chrome, press F12 to open the developer console and see those errors.

You should delay attaching those handlers until those elements actually exist. Somewhat along those lines:

```
document.getElementById("ButtonA").onclick = function () {
    bint.style.display = 'none';

    ButtonA.innerText = `Option A turn ${turncount}`;
    ButtonB.innerText = `Option B turn ${turncount}`;
    chA.id = ("a1A");
    chB.id = ("a1B");
    //only attach handlers, once those elements actually exist
    attachEventHandlers();
};

//wrap into function for re-use if neede.
function attachEventHandlers() {

  document.getElementById("a1A").onclick = function () {
        turncount++;
      bint.style.display = 'none';
      a1A.innerText = `Option A turn ${turncount}`;
      a1B.innerText = `Option B turn ${turncount}`;
  };

  document.getElementById("a1B").onclick = function () {
    turncount++;
    bint.style.display = 'none';
    a1A.innerText = `Option bA turn ${turncount}`;
    a1B.innerText = `Option bB turn ${turncount}`;
    };
}
```

I've done this just for buttonA so you will get the picture. Here is a fiddle to play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/apg10hr3/6/